# Construction of push down automaton from context free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton

From this [section of the Wiki article on PDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton#PDA_and_Context-free_Languages), I've got a rough idea on the construction process of a PDA from a given CFG. What this article doesn't make clear is the step required when there are **multiple production rules for a single non-terminal**.

For example suppose we have a grammar given of the form :

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Clearly, this grammar recognizes all string of the form **x(ab)*y** [coincidentally it's a regular language too].

Here I'm having problem constructing PDA from this grammar because of these 2 rules

> [image]
>
> [image]

That is, which of these 2 rules to be used in the *Expansion* phase, while pushing down to the stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As given in this [Slides](http://www.csc.lsu.edu/~busch/courses/theorycomp/fall2014/slides/PDA_Accept_Context_Free.ppt) your PDA will simulate leftmost derivations

Answer (score 1):

For More Clear Details the slides have an example.